# Функция для проверки вхождения подстроки в строку

Tags: функции, mysql

Извините, если вопрос туповат, я честно пытался найти самостоятельно ответ на него, но не смог.

У меня есть строка типа `",1,3,5,9,"`, где цифры - `id` выученных персонажем скилов. Необходимо сформировать такой запрос, чтобы он выдавал в ответ записи всех скилов, выученных персонажем. Если подскажете функцию, которая возвращает `boolean` входит ли подстрока в строку, я все доделаю сам. Находил функции `FINDSTRING()` и `OCCURE()`, но мне было вежливо сказано, что таких функций не существует.

P.S. Да, возможно, такой способ не очень правильный, но мне интересен именно он. Прога, реализующая это через 3-ю таблицу, таблицу `select`, которая содержит `id` перса и `id` скила, уже написана и работает, но это скучно :)

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: ...where skills like '%3%';

Comment: Если это скучно, то попробуйте noSQL решения, а именно - mongodb, couchdb.

С SQL'ем такого рода "хаки", в большинстве случаев, лучше не практиковать, а в noSQL в них нет необходимости.

Answer (score 1):

```
select skills.id
from pers, skills
where
pers.skills like concat(',%',skills.id,'%,')
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WHERE skills REGEXP '^skill.id$|^skill.id,|,skill.id,|,skill.id$'
```